# Modeling Presence/Absence with spatio-temporally correlated predictors (GAM)

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model

I'm trying to model presence/absence data obtained from a transect in a GAM framework and have a really hard time with this. We're trying to identify patterns of occurrence (if existent) as well as other potential influencing factors.

Because it's presence/absence data, I'm fitting a binomial GAM.

`gam.binomial<-gam(presence ~ s(Long, Lat) + s(julian) + s(Temp_C) + s(d_200.km) + s(d_Kona.km) + s(site.area), data=df, family = 'binomial', method='REML')`

This is a very large dataset with n>90,000 and we're essentially measuring continuous data (presence/absence is determined every 60s while slowly moving along the transect).

Our data also has established inherent seasonality (migrating species),but this is one of our main questions, whether that seasonal pattern remains in a different area (our study area) and how much of our observed variation is due to said seasonality, if remaining a factor, and how much due to other factors.

`plot(gam.binomial, scheme=2, page=1, se=T, shade=T, scale=0, hcolors=heat.colors(999, rev =T), contour.col='transparent', rug=T)`

[image: GAM Partial Effects]

Here are my questions/concerns:

**Question 1:**
Because of the nature of our transect (2 months over a huge area), our spatial and temporal covariates are autocorrelated. I am unsure whether I’m violating anything because of their autocorrelation? I thought this is exactly why I fit a GAM to see how much of the observed variability is explained by each of those covariates in the presence of the other covariate(s), but am unsure about the autocorrelation/concurvity part in this case.

**Question 2:**
I'm fitting binary data (i.e. 0/1), but I absolutely do not understand the y-axes in the effect plots. How do I interpret the numbers as they're clearly not probability?

**Question 3:**
When I `gam.check()`, my spatial 2D smoother keeps being significant (p<2e-16) and I keep having to increase k dramatically (k>300), but in the process I’m loosing any and all signal in the other covariates. That can’t be right?

**Question 4:**
Since we have continuous data (basically without replicates), I'm wondering whether I should subsample (e.g. take a sample every hour) or somehow bin the Lat/Long somehow (to tackle the problem with finding the correct k described in question 3. We're not interested in fine-scale patterns at the scale of our sample rate but in broad patterns

**Question 5:**
Maybe this is an artifact of 1) and 3), but the effect plots are contradictory. For example, in the spatial heatmap our response decreases with increasing Lat/Long, but increases with d_Kona. But d_Kona increases with increasing Lat/Long (the reference point is in the lower right corner of the heatmap plot), so that can’t be right? I understand those are *partial* effect plots so each effect is in the presence of the others, but I just can't wrap my head around this.

**Question 6:**
*site_area* is in theory a continuous variable, but in reality for our data is more of a grouping variable (basically a ranked factor?). Should I include it as a factor instead of as a smooth term?

Thank you!

Comment: Autocorrelation of predictors is not an issue. What is an issue is autocorrelation of residuals. I expect that this is a strong concern with your data. You should test for that and model autocorrelation, e.g., by using `gamm`.

Comment: Re. 3) That sounds like collinearity is an issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not very experienced with gam/gamm and wouldn't know how to test for the autocorrelation of the residuals (variogram?) and how to model any of this with a gamm.